# Как сделать, чтобы AlertDialog не закрывался при нажатии на PositiveButton?

Tags: android, java, android-sources

Подскажите.

У меня `AlertDialog` должен выводить `Input` форму, если в этой форме нет данных, то диалог закрываться не должен. Сейчас я пытаюсь его просто вызвать заново, но ничего не выходит.

Вот код:

```
case IDD_SET_DOP_CATEGORY_FLAT_PRICE:

builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("Cтоимость до:");
final EditText input = new EditText(this);
builder.setView(input);
builder.setPositiveButton("Дальше", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(input.getText().toString())) {
            String value = input.getText().toString();
            GoToCreateRecordActivity();
        } else {
            showDialog(IDD_SET_DOP_CATEGORY_FLAT_PRICE);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: нет же проблемы написать свой диалог с 2мя кнопками (да/нет) и не выходить по кнопке да если текст не введен

Comment: в чем тут вообще может быть проблема?

Comment: во во! ....

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос хоть и старый, но все еще актуальный, сам недавно решал подобную проблему.
Решается это просто, и не надо никаких кастомных диалогов лепить.
По умолчанию диалог всегда закрывается по нажатии на любую из кнопок, чтобы это обойти надо:

1. не задавать кнопке DialogInterface.OnClickListener

   ```
   builder.setPositiveButton("Дальше", null);
   ```
2. Сразу после отображения диалога переопределить у кнопки `View.OnClickListener`

   ```
   dialog = builder.create();  
   dialog.show();  
   dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener(myOnClickListener);
   ```
3. Не забывать, что теперь Ваш `myOnClickListener` отвечает за закрытие диалога.

Comment: Типа того: new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // TODO Do something

                //Dismiss once everything is OK.
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
Разумеется, dialog должен быть final.

Comment: Почему вы решили что `DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE` это `ID` кнопки? А еще лучше, задайте свой вопрос, вам помогут.